# The affects of heat on the tree inside the house

Tags: heat, tree

The tree , if you use a tree as the only support and the tree runs through the treehousefrom bottom to top and sealed in , how does winter heat affect the tree ?

Comment: As in heat from a heater in the treehouse?   It might damage the tree.  I know just sunlight on a tree in cold temperatures can do damage and shade is sometimes recommended.  This might be better on  https://gardening.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The type of tree and the growing zone/general area will be needed also.